# Can't Import .ppt Files Into My iOS App

Tags: ios, import, powerpoint, mime-types, uti

I'm currently having an issue importing **.ppt** files into my iOS app.  So far, every single one of these UTI's are working and allow me to import their corresponding file types into my app. This includes docx, doc, xslx, xsl, pptx.  The ONLY one that refuses to let me import (my app's icon never shows up) is **.ppt**.

I used the UTI's from Apple's official site and it still does not work: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

Any ideas?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Document File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.wordml</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation</string>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.bmp</string>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
            <string>public.png</string>
            <string>public.tiff</string>
            <string>com.compuserve.gif</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Did you try to look up the UTI for your PPT file on the commandline? Would be interesting to know what UTI macOS reports. You can do this wil the following command: `mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree /path/to/file`

Comment: Yes and here it is.   

kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.presentation",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the reason.  Do not copy and paste the UTI into your Plist file or any other string for that matter. It was the same exact characters except there was an invisible Unicode character between the '.' and 'ppt'. If you step through the string with arrow keys, you'll notice you must tap twice to move past the 'p' in 'ppt' because there is a character there.

Once I typed out the UTI myself, it worked.

Comment: Damn! you were right. An invisible character was in between . and ppt when copy-pasted the entire value from the apple documentation